# how to merge the dataset

Tags: c#, ado.net, merge, dataset

hai friends

### I am one dataset like this ds like  three columns this:

### tblkey   Empkey    Empname

T101     E10           Natraj
T102     E11           Siva
T103     E14          ganesh

### I am having another dataset ds1 only two columns  like this:

Empkey        Empname
E10           karthi
E11           thriu
E13           maran

i waant merge the dataset and check the values  while checking  if ds is not having E13 it should bind and show the result like this  ds

### tblkey   Empkey    Empname

T101     E10           Natraj
T102     E11           Siva
T103     E14          ganesh
         E13           maran
here 'tblkey' comes empty
how to do:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replicate your example entirely:

```
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();

ds1.Tables.Add(new DataTable());
ds2.Tables.Add(new DataTable());

ds1.Tables[0].Columns.Add("tblkey");
ds1.Tables[0].Columns.Add("empkey");
ds1.Tables[0].Columns.Add("empname");

ds2.Tables[0].Columns.Add("empkey");
ds2.Tables[0].Columns.Add("empname");

ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Add("T101", "E10", "Natraj");
ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Add("T102", "E11", "Siva");
ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Add("T103", "E14", "ganesh");

ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Add("E10", "karthi");
ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Add("E11", "thriu");
ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Add("E13", "maran");

// primary keys must be set in order for the merge to work
ds1.Tables[0].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { ds1.Tables[0].Columns["empkey"] };
ds2.Tables[0].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { ds2.Tables[0].Columns["empkey"] };

// this is the critical line
ds1.Merge(ds2, true, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
```

Adding the missing schema (in this case, the tblkey column) is achieved by setting the third parameter correctly.